# How to import a package or a module from a string

Tags: python, string, import

Let's say I want to import some packages or modules but using a string as module names:

```py
import numpy as np
```

but with numpy as string: 'numpy'

and the same thing with:

```py
from IPython.display import display as dd
```

I already know:

`import numpy as np`

is equal to:

```py
np = __import__('numpy')
```

but when i want to import a module from a package normally imported with the keyword `from` like:

```py
join = __import__('os.path.join')
```

I got

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os.path.join'; 'os.path' is not a package
```

Yet `from os.path import join` works...

The python documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#from) says:

```py
import foo.bar.baz         # foo.bar.baz imported, foo bound locally
from foo.bar import baz    # foo.bar.baz imported and bound as baz
```

So, `from os.path import join` should be equal to `import os.path.join`, no ?

How to import (for exemple) os.path.join as string, like `join = __import__('os.path.join')` ?

Comment: join = __import__("os").path.join

Answer (score 2):

use importlib instead. Its specifically made for importing module names as strings.

```py
    import importlib
    module = importlib.import_module('numpy')
    print(module.__version__)
    print(module.zeros([3, 3]))
```